# How to inline the same key values into one line

Tags: python-2.7, awk, sed

How to inline the same key values into one line, i have below entries into the file(file1.txt) where the very First column have the Key(Server Name) and the Forth column has the IP's this Key belongs to, hence i'm looking around the way  to Inline all the IP's into One Line of the Same Key name.

```
keanx61.ddl.COM            out:  nameserver  192.22.48.33
keanx61.ddl.COM            out:  nameserver  192.22.48.23
keanx61.ddl.COM            out:  nameserver  172.144.71.11
```

> I Just tried `awk` as follows but it wraps up entire output into one.

```
$ cat file1.txt | column -t  | tr -d '[]'| tr -d 'out:'  | tr -d 'nameserver' | awk 'NR%3{printf "%s ",$0;next;}1'


keanx61.ddl.COM       192.22.48.33 keanx61.ddl.COM  192.22.48.23 keanx61.ddl.COM   172.144.71.11
```

any way to get it via awk,python or other way will help. I used awk for number of occurrences 3 but it may be less or more so looking around for the ideas.

Comment: show the desired output for your current input example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `Awk` logic as

```
awk '{key[$1]=(key[$1] FS $NF); next}END{for (i in key) print i,key[i]}' file
```

which will produce an output as

```
keanx61.ddl.COM  192.22.48.33 192.22.48.23 172.144.71.11
```

The idea is to create a hash-map with the key value in `$1` and the IP value in the last column `$NF`. Once all the lines are parsed, we print the key, value pair in the `END{}` clause. Here the value is a list of the IPs available for the given key.

The solution can scale for any different number of keys with their corresponding IPs too.

Comment: ....thx for solution  I dont want `keanx61.ddl.COM` to be repeated only at first place.

Comment: @KarnKumar: Updated, check it now!

Comment: Inian: That I'll do for sure :) .. just trying to understand the logic you produced just to be sure if that i understand or if any doubt i could ask you before i close it :)

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{a[$1][NR]=$4}END{for(i in a){ r=i; for(nr in a[i]){r=r" "a[i][nr]} print r}}' file.txt
```

The output:

```
keanx61.ddl.COM 192.22.48.33 192.22.48.23 172.144.71.11
```

---

*Details*:

- `a[$1][NR]=$4` - multidimensional array, accumulating all *IPs* for each *hostname*
- `r=r" "a[i][nr]` - concatenating *IP* addresses for each *hostname*

---

***Python*** solution:

```
import re, collections
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:      # reading the file
    d = collections.defaultdict(str)  # `string` is a prototype for the `d` (dict) values
    for l in f.read().splitlines():   # splitting the lines
        parts = re.split(r'\s+', l)   # split the line by whitespace characters (sequence)
        d[parts[0]] += " " + parts[3] # collecting IPs for each hostname

print '\n'.join(k+" "+v for k,v in d.items())
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: Roman.... Its giving some error unexpected newline error..

`awk: cmd. line:1: {a[$1][NR]=$4}END{for(i in a){ r=i; for(nr in a[i]){r=r" "a[i][nr]} print r}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                             ^ unexpected newline or end of string
bash-4.1$
`

Comment: looks like a  syntex error..

` a[i]){r=r" "a[i
 ^ syntax error`

Comment: @KarnKumar, damn, once again. That's the last. Check it, should work (I just hate when I'm missing some character)

Comment: @KarnKumar, let me show you some Python 2.7 approach

Comment: @KarnKumar, here we go! Python solution is on!

Comment: RomanPerekhrest, many thanks for the another solution in place , it works if i use it for one host if there are 1000 lines then it says Indexerror, that i'm checking on..


`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dn.py", line 8, in <module>
    d[parts[0]] += " " + parts[3] # collecting IPs for each hostname
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @KarnKumar, such an error can occur if some of your lines are out of valid format